# How to make a hover clickable?

Tags: html

I'm using a jquery to use the fade in effect on an image but the only thing that's clickable is the link inside the image not the image itself, and surrounding the 'img' tag with an 'a' tag did not work, here's my my problem: http://www.marcuspedersen.com/dev/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The link is clickable by virtue of being a link. If you want to make something else clickable, you would have to bind a click listener to it. In your case, you'd want to add a listener to the `<p class="link">`:

```
$(function() {
   $('p.link').click(function() {
      // stuff to do when p is clicked
   });
});
```

To follow the link once you've received a click, you could write

```
location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```